# How to detect if a string contains PHP code? PHP

Tags: php, security, code-injection, sanitization, mysql-real-escape-string

I am keeping record of every request made to my website. I am very aware of the security measurements that need to be taken before executing any MySQL query that contains data coming from query strings. I clean it as much as possible from injections and so far all tests have been successful using:

`htmlspecialchars, strip_tags, mysqli_real_escape_string`.

But on the logs of pages visited I find query strings of failed hack attempts that contain a lot of php code:

```
?1=%40ini_set%28"display_errors"%2C"0"%29%3B%40set_time_limit%280%29%3B%40set_magic_quotes_runtime%280%29%3Becho%20%27->%7C%27%3Bfile_put_contents%28%24_SERVER%5B%27DOCUMENT_ROOT%27%5D.%27/webconfig.txt.php%27%2Cbase64_decode%28%27PD9waHAgZXZhb
```

In the previous example we can see:

`display_errors, set_time_limit, set_magic_quotes_runtime, file_put_contents`

Another example:

```
/?s=/index/%5Cthink%5Capp/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=file_put_contents&vars[1][]=ctlpy.php&vars[1][]=<?php @assert($_REQUEST["ysy"]);?>ysydjsjxbei37$
```

This one is worst, there is even some `<?php` and `$_REQUEST["ysy"]` stuff in there. Although I am able to sanitize it, strip tags and encode `<` or `>` when I decode the string I can see the type of requests that are being sent.

Is there any way to detect a string that contains php code like:

```
filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_PHP);
```

*FYI: This is not a real function, I am trying to give an idea of what I am looking for.*

or some sort of function:

```
function findCode($var){
   return ($var contains PHP) ? true : false
}
```

*Again, not real*

No need to sanitize, that has been taken care of, just to detect PHP code in a string. I need this because I want to detect them and save them in other logs.

**NOTE: NEVER EXECUTE OR EVAL CODE COMING FROM QUERY STRINGS**

Comment: Could it be a starting point to log unusual **long** request strings?

Comment: First of all, just don't `eval`

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen NEVER!!!! LOL

Comment: Check to see if it's code with for example: https://phpcodechecker.com/api/

Comment: Please don't suggest him to use an api for each query. Security is even more of a reason here than performance. The Query could contain sensitive data you really DON'T wan't to send to 3rd parties on the internet.

Comment: Visiters can submit any query with a request. It could contain PHP, but also Javascript (think: XSS) and possibly other harmful stuff (language, pictures, etc). It's a fact of live. It is up to you to only accept those parameters you actually need, and then only those values that are permissible for those parameters. Storing every request doesn't make your site safer. Making sure you don't do anything stupid, with stuff that shouldn't be permitted, does.

Comment: I'd suggest using regex.

Comment: "I need this because I want to detect them and not save them in my logs." — This sounds like a terrible idea. If you do have a security breach then having logs of the attempts to make it are really useful!

Comment: What's the harm in having this stuff in log files? By itself it's just text. Unless you explicitly try to execute it as PHP code, it won't do anything. That's pretty much what all attacks boil down to: *don't try to execute user input as PHP/SQL/HTML etc.*, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware, it is not about making it safer, regardless of the benefits or disadvantages of doing so, maybe big data, or analytics, robot tracking, referrals, seo, hack attempts analyisis, etc, etc,I simply want to know if there is a way to detect PHP code in a string. Thanks!

Comment: The better questions is why one would need this? If php code in strings coming from your database is a problem, then something else is terribly wrong.

Comment: Consider that Stack Overflow deals with PHP code in requests sent to it all the time, and most probably not by discarding it. You've sent PHP to Stack Overflow to post this very question…

Comment: You were talking about "failed hack attempts", and "worse" attempts, but you managed to sanatize it. Then your question is: "Is there any way to detect and _sanitize_ a string that contains php code?". It sounds very much to me like you're doing this for safety reasons.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, nope, I really want to track visits to my site and ignore the hundreds of attacks that we receive per day, lets say that Google analytics doesn't provide the information that we need. again, regardless of the usage, "Is there any way to detect a string that contains php code?" No need to sanitize, that has been taken care of.

Comment: @xcy7e I don't know what you mean, the code is not in our database, I don't think you are understanding the question properly. Thanks

Comment: OK, I understand. The answer is: No, not reliably (this is the short answer...). You also say: "I am very aware of the security measurements that need to be taken before executing any MySQL query that contains data coming from query strings.". However sanatizing with `htmlspecialchars()`, `strip_tags()` and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not the right method. Better use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). Here's [an explanation](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware we also use prepare statements, that is not really a concern, but thanks for the help, I am almost sure that is not possible, but sometimes the community has amazing solutions to problems like this. Thanks again.

Comment: You could run an unsanatize value through the [PHP tokenizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) and then check which tokens are returned. That's the best way I can think of.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware That sounds like a great idea to explore!!! Would you like adding it as an elaborated answer, I would definitely up vote it! A function to tokenize and find the length of tokes found...Wow I love the idea!

Comment: I don't think writing a reliable answer with the [PHP tokenizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) is all that easy. First of all, there can be a `<?php` start or not, so you need to run it twice, then you need to classify all the tokens. It's just a lot of effort, and by now you get idea, so why bother?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'll write the solution and give some credits. Thanks mate!

Comment: That's fine, having an answer to your question is good for the readers of this site.

Comment: This is a job for an [Intrusion Detection System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system), not your server or application. No amount of stripping, escaping, or *whatever* can protect you from when an application allows remote code execution through some vector. Any public server gets hammered with all kinds of ridiculous junk all the time. An IDS tool can help filter out the types of alerts you're interested in.

Comment: I've never had to use any code to fix a problem as OP has stated. I've had plenty of attempts to mess my code up via funky requests, bit if you just stick to good practices (eg never trust input, dont just use REQUEST etc), this kind of solutions will cause more harm via weird behaviour and slowing down than it does good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading lots of comments @KIKO Software came up with an ingenious idea by using PHP tokenizer, but it ended up being extremely difficult because the string that is to be analyzed needed to have almost prefect syntax or it would fail.

So the best solution that I came up with is a simple function that tries to find commonly used PHP statements, In my case, especially on query strings with code injection. Another advantage of this solution is that we can modify and add to the list as many PHP statements as we want. **Keep in mind that making the list bigger will considerably slow down your script.**  this functions uses strpos instead of preg_match (regex ) as its proven to perform faster.

**This will not find 100% PHP code inside a string, but you can customize it to find as much as is required, never include terms that could be used in regular English, like 'echo' or 'if'**

```
function findInStr($string, $findarray){
    $found=false;   
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($findarray);$i++){
        $res=strpos($string,$findarray[$i]);
        if($res !== false){
            $found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
```

Simply use:

```
$search_line=array(
            'file_put_contents',
            '<?=',
            '<?php',
            '?>',
            'eval(',
            '$_REQUEST',
            '$_POST',
            '$_GET',
            '$_SESSION',
            '$_SERVER',
            'exec(',
            'shell_exec(',
            'invokefunction',
            'call_user_func_array',
            'display_errors',
            'ini_set',
            'set_time_limit',
            'set_magic_quotes_runtime',
            'DOCUMENT_ROOT',
            'include(',
            'include_once(',
            'require(',
            'require_once(',
            'base64_decode',
            'file_get_contents',
            'sizeof',
            'array('
        );

if(findInStr("this has some <?php echo 'PHP CODE' ?>",$search_line)){
  echo "PHP found";
}
```

Comment: You could broaden it with a regex instead: `/[a-z_]{1,}\(|\$_[a-z]{3,7}/i`. Tiny bit less secure, but it catches the function calls and super globals. For a simple check, this should be enough.